# Using a digital ammeter to loop power a pressure gauge

Tags: gauge

I'm trying to set up a digital pressure gauge which gives out a 4-20mA signal and needs to be loop powered. Rather than buying a digital pressure meter, I'm thinking of purchasing a 12-30 VDC power supply, which I'll connect through a digital ammeter in series with the power supply. I have the calibration files to relate output current to pressure.

Does this seem like a reasonable approach? What would be the benefit of purchasing a dedicated digital pressure display: wouldn't that require more steps of calibration (from gauge -> current and current -> display)?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: I don't see any benefit in precision or price doing that, just lots of troubles.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Would you recommend I purchase something like this instead of using the ammeter:
http://www.bdsensors.de/en/evaluation/displays/details/produkt/pa-440/

Comment: Of course, but there are amny of them, perhaps in the link is an overkill: it has Ex certificate that you may not need it. You should search for panel meter 4..20mA, and a small PSU. I had been using cheap Lumel panel meters, but the dealer had to program it first to match the span and offset 4-20ma to displayed numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is completely reasonable.

Your task will be easier if the digital current meter has adjustable offset and gain. This will make it easier to match the display to the measured values.

Ensure that the power supply voltage is greater than the burden voltage of the transducer plus the burden voltage of the current meter. I prefer to exceed the minimum required voltage by at least 30% or more.